# How to change the Permisions in Spring Security ACL?

Tags: java, spring-security, acl

I want to extend the permissions given for an user to an entity.

I am able to create ACLs via `MutableAclService`.

```
MutableAcl acl = this.mutableAclService.createAcl(new ObjectIdentityImpl(entity));            
acl.setOwner(SYSTEM_PRINCIPAL_SID);
acl.insertAce(0, permission, grantToSid, true);
this.mutableAclService.updateAcl(acl);
```

But I don't know how to change ACLs. For example if a user has Read Privileges to an entity, I want to provide him additional Write Privileges.
Or give an other user the same privileges.

---

My first try was to invoke `MutableAclService.createAcl` twice, but that failed:

> org.springframework.security.acls.model.AlreadyExistsException: Object identity 'org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ObjectIdentityImpl[Type: test.Entity; Identifier: 3]' already exists

Ok that seams to be correct, wrong way.  But how to do it then? **How to change the acl permissions for an entity where already some permissions are defined?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a look at the code, and it seams that there is only one relevant implementation of the ACL interface: `AclImpl`.

This class implements the `MutableAcl` interface and is returned by the `AclService` functions.

So I decided to cast the results from `Acl` to `MutableAcl`. Up to now it is working and I did not get an problem or Class cast exception:

```
MutableAcl existingAcl = (MutableAcl) mutableAclService.readAclById(oid, sids);
...
mutableAclService.updateAcl(existingAcl);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you already have the answer, if you have created a `MutableAcl`, you can simply call the `updateAcl` method of the `MutableAclService`. Provided the contract of this method is implemented correctly (if you are using a custom implementation), it should:

- Delete all ACEs from the current ACL for that entity
- Create all new ACEs based on the `MutableAcl` you passed into `updateAcl`
- Update all relevant fields on the `ObjectIdentity`
- Update ACL cache

The only downside of this is that it assumes a "wipe and load" strategy for the ACL, it's not meant to *incrementally* add ACEs and other stuff to an existing ACL. This means you should probably be reading the ACL in its entirety first, before you modify it, so that you don't inadvertently blow away any ACEs that are already on the principal.

Hope that helps!